# TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 1D

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I have successfully plotted an excel data to make a 3d plot. Now I want to plot it to make a contour map. But somehow it resulted an error. could someone help me?

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx')
print(df.head())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x = df['Ex Wavelength(nm)']
y = df['Em Wavelength(nm)']

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = df['Intensity(cnt)']
cp = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
fig.colorbar(cp)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add dummy data, so we can run it.

Comment: look at `X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)`, X and Y are both 2D arrays, so naturally Z has to be a 2D array as well

Comment: Without knowing which form your x and y have, the most probable way to get this working would be `ax.tricontourf(x, y, df['Intensity(cnt)'])` using the 1D data.